# Eclipse: Nothing to build for file

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, windows

I did look up on the Internet to find the solution for my problems, unfortunately all advices didn't seem to help so perhaps you will be more helpful in my case.

I did set up my Eclipse IDE with MinGW,
I did set up my Windows' environment variables right, for example:
added `C:\Program Files\eclipse; C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin`
and somehow managed to create project with `.cpp` file that actually worked, at the beggining I build this file and than run it with these simple icons. Somehow, it compiled without errors and output the right results.

I hoped that it would remain perfect for eternity, but somehow today while dealing with new c++ project I have encountered the following problems.

I build new C++ project, by clicking:
`File` -> `New` -> `C++ Project` -> marking executable project `Hello World Project` -> by default I set up to use MinGW toolchain (nothing has changed since the moment it worked perfectly smooth) -> name project and start work.

Building project looks ok, I get no errors whatsover. But when I try to run it the console window is completely blank - with popping info: Nothing to build for [project name].

I really hope that once I've made some project actually work all changes will remain untouched and that I will not have to fiddle around once again with all these settings. 
I did not change anything at all and now it doesn't work...

1. Right click on project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Environment -> all variables are set.
2. Toolchain set to MinGW which has worked so well.

And yet I can't run this executable program, this IDE is really starting to drive me crazy.

Any idea what might have happened over the last magical six hours when suddenly Eclipse refuse to work properly again ?

Comment: Alright, I got it. It all has something to do with so-called: Launch configuration. Once, I've right-click on project -> Select Properties -> Run/Debug Settings -> and added new Launch configuration for this project including PATH with C:/MinGW it all started to work perfectly fine. Now the question is how can I set it by default so that I won't have to create new Launch configuration time and again ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to right click the eclipse project and click refresh. An item should appear under executables. If an item appears you should be able to run it from inside eclipse (not sure how though, maybe by double clicking or from the right click menu) or by using the command promt. To run it through the command prompt, using cd command browse to the folder where the executable file resides (somewhere inside the project folder inside your workspace folder) and run it by typing the name of the executable (fx hello.exe or just hello).